# Tastypie api working with postman but not with python requests

Tags: python, django, tastypie, postman

I have tastypie api with api key authentication.

Its working both ways for GET request, but for post request, it is not working.

```
url = http://localhost:8000/api/path/?api_key=key&username=username
```

in the view, when I tried to print request.user, it is regular/real user when request comes from postman. But with python requests, it is anonymous user.

With python requests, I am doing this:

```
url = http://localhost:8000/api/path/?api_key=key&username=username
d = {"some": "data"}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(d), headers={"content-type": "application/json"})
```

Code provided by postman:

```
POST /api/v1/abc/?api_key=somekey&username=something HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: something

{"something":"something"}
```

Please let me know for any questions.

My Resource for which api authentication not working:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    resource_name = 'user'
    authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
```

Comment: What kind of authentication you are using?

Comment: Its api key authentication.

Comment: Can you add the code(in your question) of the request while sending via Postman? Code link will be provided just below save button.

Comment: Thanks Abijith, updated question. Please check.

Comment: Some issue with your api key i guess! And also url u have mentioned differs from postman url!

Comment: Why is it working with postman then ? I am confused !

Comment: url u have mentioned differs from postman url!

Comment: Both are same actually. Also, postman lets us convert it to python requests code and curl code. Both are not working too :) But postman working

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not using `SessionAuthentication` too or have `enforce_csrf` enabled in your authentication. Since postman sends the browser cookies with the request too, that probably might be the reason for the different behaviour you are getting.

If that is the case, it means API Authentication is not working. Since postman is using SessionAuthentication, so it works. Ensure that you have added tastypie in INSTALLED_APPS and created/stored the api key in the database.

Comment: Seems correct, because I have seen that cookies is being set by postman(I saw in server logs). But I am using         authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication().

Also, we have website as well as api in same server so we are using sessionauthentication. But for individual api, we have apikeyauthentication.

What is the solution ?

Comment: Most probably the way you are providing authentication credentials is not correct. Try to fix that

Comment: Done, please check updated question. i added my resource.

Comment: Ensure that you have added tastypie in INSTALLED_APPS and created/stored the api key in the database.